# Date field getting truncated to 12:00:00 Hrs upon Join in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am creating a table from the join of three other tables and partitioning it over a date field. However this date field is getting truncated to 12:00:00 Hours for every entry. What am I doing wrong?

```
select /*+ USE_HASH(A, B, C)*/
       id, status, region, dated
from 
 (
   select dated, id, region
   from   A inner join B
   on     A.id = B.id
   and    trunc(B.dated) = trunc(to_date('2012/12/12', 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
 ) AB
inner join C
on  AB.id = C.id
and AB.region = C.region
```

When I see the output of this table the dated field seems to have been truncated to 12:00:00 hours, whereas the dated field from table B has the correct time till seconds.

---

Table definitions:

```
Table A - (id number not null, region number not null)
Table B - (id number not null, dated date not null)
Table C - (id number not null, region number not null, status varchar not null)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You'll need to post your table definitions..

Comment: you could never lose the timestamp details of the date from your select.. how do you validate the output? you see it in sqlplus or any oci clients? (php,jdbc,odbc..adodb.etc)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't selecting `A.dated` anywhere in this query. The `dated` column you're selecting is the one from your subquery `(AB)`, which comes from table `B

Try this instead:

```
select /*+ USE_HASH(A, B, C)*/
   id, status, region, dateda, datedb
from 
 (
   select A.dated dateda, B.dated datedb, id, region
   from   A inner join B
   on     A.id = B.id
   and    trunc(B.dated) = trunc(Sysdate)
 ) AB
inner join C
on  AB.id = C.id
and AB.region = C.region
```

and you should see whats happening

Comment: Table A doesn't have the date field. Only table B has it.

Comment: In that case there is nothing much wrong with your SQL. Are you sure it is being truncated? Are you sure it isn't the correct output i.e. the rows matching your selection criteria definitely don't all have 12:00:00 as the time?

Answer (score 0):

You select only "id" and "region" without any table definition:

```
select /*+ USE_HASH(A, B, C)*/
       id, status, region, dated
from 
 (
   select dated, id, region
   from   A inner join B
```

Since you join on it, it actually does not matter. However, you should get an error `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`. In some Oracle release have a bug not raising the error when you use ANSI join.

Did you post your entire query?